# Remote OSGI using ECF: Bundle Requirements For BND

Tags: osgi, bndtools, dosgi

Can some one point what bundles am I missing in this bndrun file for registering a remote service in OSGI framework. I followed the following example in the link [Building your first remote osgi service](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tutorial:_Building_your_first_OSGi_Remote_Service).

I have registered a service like this:

```
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Dictionary<String, String> props = new Hashtable<>();
    props.put("service.exported.interfaces", "*");
    props.put("service.exported.configs", "ecf.generic.server");
    context.registerService(ITimeService.class.getName(),
                new TimeServiceImpl(), props);
}
```

Here is my runrequires section of bndrun file:

```
runrequires: \
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.siu.casa.timeservice.host.org.siu.casa.timeservice.host.api.impl)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.siu.casa.timeservice.host.org.siu.casa.timeservice.api)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.command)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.apache.felix.gogo.shell)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(&(osgi.identity=org.osgi.service.event)(version>=1.3.1))',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf.discovery)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf.identity)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf.osgi.services.remoteserviceadmin)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf.osgi.services.remoteserviceadmin.proxy)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.remoteservice)',\
osgi.identity;filter:='(&(osgi.identity=org.eclipse.equinox.registry)(version>=3.5.400))'
```